# i want to remove timestamp in date how can i solve this problem using flutter

Tags: flutter, api, dart, datetime, timestamp

My program output is `2022-11-17 15:06:59.422` i want to remove this `timestamp`.
**This is my button code:**

```
 child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      String startDate = startDateController.text;

                      String duration = durationController.text;

                      DateTime thirtyDaysFromNow =
                          DateTime.now().add(new Duration(days: 12));

                      setState(() {
                        startDate;
                        duration;
                        endDateController.text = thirtyDaysFromNow.toString();
                      });

                      print(thirtyDaysFromNow);
                    },
                    child: const Text("Save"),
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                        backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                            Color.fromARGB(255, 3, 89, 168))),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DateFormat class in Flutter: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html

To get your output you can use the following code:

```
final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
final String formatted = formatter.format(your date);
```

Comment: i want to when i select start date the end date automatically comes using months like 12, 24, 36, 48 in flutter .

Comment: You can use the function add for DateTime: yourDate.add(Duration(months: 12))

Comment: DateTime: yourDate.add(Duration(months: 12)) can you please explain how can i used this function without hardcoded value of month.

Comment: i was try to add months but the months are not taken .

Comment: Ah sorry, my fault. Maybe you can add hours? Like 365 * 24 hours?